# Как поставить MAC OS на компьютер с процессором AMD

Tags: mac, установка, ос

Всем привет, хочу поставить себе на свой компьютером MAC или еще как говорят хакинтош. Сам такого еще никогда не делал. Подскажите с чего начать и что нужно для того чтобы поставить хакинтош на свой пк.

**Вот мои характеристики.**

Видео карточка - NVIDIA GeForce GTX 550 Ti

Процессор -  AMD Athlon(tm) II X2 250 Processor
Установленная память - 8GB DDR3

*Заранние благодарен Вам за помощь.*

Comment: Вы же задавали [подобный вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/530347/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-mac-os-%D0%BD%D0%B0-pc-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-amd) и ссылку даже там приводили [Установка](http://osxamd.ru/own-image/#Установка). Но как по мне, так самый правильный способ установить мак - это купить именно мак. Все остальное - извращения. 

P.S. Самый правильный способ поставить мак - это не ставить мак:)

Comment: @KoVadim, та не, купить mac а потом жалеть если что, лучше сначала попробовать саму ос. У меня у знакомого стоит мак на обычном пк но правда ставил его ему другой человек. Вот если мне сама ос понравится тогда я уже буду думать либо о покупке либо о сборке под саму ос

Comment: найдите этого "другого человека", пусть он Вам поставит. Но я бы рекомендовал ставить линукс - оно лучше.

Comment: @KoVadim, на linux нет продукции от adobe, фотошопа, флеша и так далее, а на мак есть. С linux проблемы с софтом. Эсли честно тоя бы и на виндовсе сидел бы себе тихо, но эти долгие загрузки программ и их неудобство как то достало меня. А в маке смотрю все быстро, плавно и просто, по этому и хочу попробовать его.

Comment: Нет проблем с софтом на линуксе. Честно. А вот если хотите "плавности", купите себе просто ssd под систему. 128 будет достаточно на первое время. И, если памяти 4 гигабайта, добавьте до 12 хотя бы. И Вы  не узнаете свою машину.

P.S. Флеш не нужен. На нем только реклама.

Comment: @KoVadim, ну да про ssd я тоже задумывался. Вообщем я тут почитал немного и пришел к тому что систему мне мою надо апгрейдить, подкупить как Вы говорили ssd докинуть еще 4 памати и купить процесор от intel, ну и карточку вообщем то тоже можно поменять. Тогда я смогу и мак поставить и посмотреть как будет работать винда. Вообщем вопрос по установке mac решен.