# Установка windows на imac 8

Tags: windows, macos, ос

Имеется imac 8 с установленной на нем winodws 10, которая нереально глючит(и драйвер на видеокарту падает каждые полчаса). Os x на машине отсутствует, только винда. Возможно ли отформатировать hdd и "ровно" установить windows 7 не имея osx, только windows, используя флешку и дополнительный комп с виндой?

Comment: За такое могут к расстрелу приговорить.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, из-за отсутствия os x? тем не менее, это реально сделать?

Comment: За богохульство. А так конечно вполне реально, в интернете должны быть инструкции (если не опасаетесь преследований).

Comment: Glover , os x устанавливается только через Glover и больше ни как, вот может быть вам поможет это видио http://hqsong.ru/flv/videotapes/hajtek/zapusk-glover-na-hakintosh.html

Comment: @LenovoID, но мне не нужна os x - только windows

Comment: ааа ! я думал вам вернуть надо os x , запишите windows через ultra iso , и втыкайте флеху в usb перезагруз и выбирайте usb носитель и enter, загрузка пойдёт и дальше по инструкции , поное форматирование и т д

Comment: @LenovoID, а чем такой способ отличается от boot camp? и что насчет драйверов? p.s. спасибо

Comment: Вот в соседних [вопросах](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/532704/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-mac-os-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-amd) @Анатолий хочет поставить мак на pc. Может просто железом обменятся?

Comment: @KoVadim, была бы моя воля - давно поставил бы пк. но это не в моих силах

Comment: если это домашняя машина - не вижу смысла мучатся. Если это рабочая машина - не вижу смысла там дальше работать. Проще сменить работу.

Comment: @KoVadim, машина не домашняя и не рабочая. Она стоит у клиента, у которого помимо нашего софта присутствует софт, который совместим только с виндоусом. Кто-то с "ровными" руками снес там os x, оставив только винду.

Comment: В этом случае проще возвратить клиенту денег и сказать, что подобное не саппортим.

Comment: Vladuysha   я про boot и camp не знаю , единственное могу сказать что приоритет загрузки ставится на usb в параметрах boot